# Vectorised pairwise distance

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, knn, nearest-neighbor

**TLDR**: given two tensors `t1` and `t2` that represent `b` samples of a tensor with shape `c,h,w` (i.e, every tensor has shape `b,c,h,w`), i'm trying to calculate the pairwise distance between `t1[i]` and `t2[j]` for all `i`,`j` efficiently

---

some more context - I've extracted `ResNet18` activations for both my train and test data (`CIFAR10`) and I'm trying to implement `k`-nearest-neighbours. A possible pseudo-code might be:

```
for te in test_activations:
    distances = []
    for tr in train_activations:
        distances.append(||te-tr||)
    neighbors = k_smallest_elements(distances)
    prediction(te) = majority_vote(labels(neighbors))
```

I'm trying to vectorise this process given batches from the *test* and *train* activations datasets. I've tried iterating the batches (and not the samples) and using `torch.cdist(train_batch,test_batch)`, **but I'm not quite sure how this function handles multi-dimensional tensors**, as in the [documentation](https://If%20x1%20has%20shape%20B%20%5Ctimes%20P%20%5Ctimes%20MB%C3%97P%C3%97M%20and%20x2%20has%20shape%20B%20%5Ctimes%20R%20%5Ctimes%20MB%C3%97R%C3%97M%20then%20the%20output%20will%20have%20shape%20B%20%5Ctimes%20P%20%5Ctimes%20RB%C3%97P%C3%97R.) it states

> **torch.cdist(x1, x2,...)**:
> If `x1` has shape `BxPxM` and `x2` has shape `BxRxM` then the output will have shape `BxPxR`

Which doesn't seem to handle my case (see below)

---

A minimal example can be found here:

```
b,c,h,w = 1000,128,28,28 # actual dimensions in my problem
train_batch = torch.randn(b,c,h,w)
test_batch = torch.randn(b,c,h,w)
d = torch.cdist(train_batch,test_batch)
```

You can think of `test_batch` and `train_batch` as the tensors in the for loop `for test_batch in train: for train_batch in test:...`

---

EDIT: im adding another example:
both `t1[i]` and `t2[j]` are tensors shaped `(c,h,w)`, and the distance between them is a scalar `d`. so for example, if we have

```
t1 = torch.randn(2,128,28,28)
t2 = torch.randn(2,128,28,28)
```

the distance matrix would look something like

```
[[d(t1[0],t2[0]), d(t1[0],t2[1])],
 [d(t1[1],t2[0]), d(t1[1],t2[1])]]
```

and have a shape `(2,2)` (or `(b,b)` more generally)
where `d` is the scalar distance between the two tensors `t1[i]` and `t2[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to have to reshape your data before feeding it to a builtin PyTorch operator. As you've said [`torch.cdist`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cdist.html) works with two inputs shaped `(B, P, M)` and `(B, R, M)` and returns a tensor shaped `(B, P, R)`.

Instead, you have two tensors shaped the same way: `(b, c, h, w)`. If we match those dimensions we have: `B=b`, `M=c`, while `P=h*w` (*from the 1st tensor*) and `R=h*w` (*from the 2nd tensor*). This requires flattening the spatial dimensions together and swapping the last two axes. Something like:

```
>>> x1 = train_batch.flatten(2).transpose(1,2)
>>> x2 = test_batch.flatten(2).transpose(1,2)

>>> d = torch.cdist(x1, x2)
```

Now `d` contains distance between all possible pairs `(train_batch[b, :, iy, ix], test_batch[b, :, jy, jx])` and is shaped `(b, h*w, h*w)`.

You can then apply a knn using `argmax` to retrieve the k closest neighbour from one element of the training batch to the test batch.

Comment: I'm now wondering - shouldn't I be getting a tensor shaped `(b,b)`, as when comparing the distance between two tensors shaped `(c,w,h)`, I expect a scalar

Comment: The resulting tensor contains the distance between all possible pairs of locations for each batch.

Comment: oh ok, because what I was thinking of is the pairwise distance between every two batch samples (as in the TLDR, the distance between`t1[i]`  and `t2[j]` for all `i`,`j` where those indexes represent the batch index). In that case, it is different, isn't it? As if I understand correctly, you've calculated the distance for every pair within the channel range

Comment: Can you give a minimal example with say `t1[0]` and `t2[0]`?

Comment: added in the post, hope this helps. by the way, I was thinking that given t1,t2 with shapes (b,c,h,w), I can flatten it to be (b,c*h*w) and simply calculate the pairwise of the flattened version, resulting in a (b,b) tensor. would you think that this is a reasonable measure of distance between t1 and t2?

Comment: The issue is that you haven't defined the distance between two 3D vectors, *i.e.* what `d(t1[0],t2[0])`  corresponds to. Does it make sense to compute the distance by flattening the two tensors spatially? I don't believe so.

Comment: do you maybe know what is considered common when trying to use kNN for multidimensional data? I guess it is a matter of chose in the end

Comment: Are you working with images?

Comment: ResNet activation maps (of images from cifar10), hence the bizzare shape

Comment: I would rather average pool the features on the spatial dimensions and then compute distances intra-batch. What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I found this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.10445.pdf) where they've used euclidian distance, though with no implementation details, so maybe that's an option as well. Regardless, I think that there's freedom in choosing the distance metric, as long as you're consistent throughout the entire dataset

Comment: But their feature vector seems to be extracted at the image level, not pixel-wise...